# Changing Dataframes in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

{'id': {0: 'x1',
1: 'x2',
2: 'x3',
3: 'x4',
4: 'x5',
5: 'x6',
6: 'x7',
7: 'x8',
8: 'x9',
9: 'x10'},
'trt': {0: 'cnt',
1: 'cnt',
2: 'tr',
3: 'tr',
4: 'tr',
5: 'cnt',
6: 'tr',
7: 'tr',
8: 'cnt',
9: 'cnt'},
'work.T1': {0: 0.6516556669957936,
1: 0.567737752571702,
2: 0.1135089821182191,
3: 0.5959253052715212,
4: 0.3580499750096351,
5: 0.4288094183430075,
6: 0.0519033221062272,
7: 0.2641776674427092,
8: 0.3987907308619469,
9: 0.8361341434065253},
'play.T1': {0: 0.8647212258074433,
1: 0.6153524168767035,
2: 0.7751098964363337,
3: 0.3555686913896352,
4: 0.4058499720413238,
5: 0.7066469138953835,
6: 0.8382876652758569,
7: 0.2395891312044114,
8: 0.7707715332508087,
9: 0.3558977444190532},
'talk.T1': {0: 0.5355970377568156,
1: 0.0930881295353174,
2: 0.169803041499108,
3: 0.8998324507847428,
4: 0.4226376069709658,
5: 0.7477464678231627,
6: 0.8226525799836963,
7: 0.9546536463312804,
8: 0.6854445093777031,
9: 0.5005032296758145},
'work.T2': {0: 0.2754838624969125,
1: 0.2289039448369294,
2: 0.0144339059479534,
3: 0.7289645625278354,
4: 0.2498804717324674,
5: 0.1611832766793668,
6: 0.0170426501426845,
7: 0.4861003451514989,
8: 0.1029001718852669,
9: 0.8015470046084374},
'play.T2': {0: 0.3543280649464577,
1: 0.9364325392525644,
2: 0.2458663922734558,
3: 0.4731414613779634,
4: 0.191560871200636,
5: 0.5832219698932022,
6: 0.4594731898978352,
7: 0.467434047954157,
8: 0.3998325555585325,
9: 0.5052855962421745},
'talk.T2': {0: 0.0318881559651345,
1: 0.1144675880204886,
2: 0.468935475917533,
3: 0.3969867376144975,
4: 0.8336191941052675,
5: 0.7611217433586717,
6: 0.5733564489055425,
7: 0.447508045937866,
8: 0.0838020080700516,
9: 0.2191385473124683}}

mydt = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns = ['id’, ‘trt’, 'work.T1', '', ‘play.T1’, ‘talk.T1’'work.T2', '', ‘play.T2’, ‘talk.T2’])

So I have the above dataset. How can I convert the above dataset so that it looks like the following where each unique id has a an observation at both T1 and T2? Please let me know.

[image: Desired Format]

Comment: Please provide `dt` dict as plain text not image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
names = ['play', 'talk', 'work']
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, names, i='id', j='time', sep='.', suffix='T\d')
         .sort_index().reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id time  trt      play      talk      work
0   x1   T1  cnt  0.010651  0.400500  0.774567
1   x1   T2  cnt  0.758084  0.147504  0.831137
2   x2   T1   tr  0.540774  0.960239  0.332556
3   x2   T2   tr  0.882142  0.884740  0.020044
4   x3   T1   tr  0.184434  0.842003  0.909759
5   x3   T2   tr  0.108465  0.234251  0.954427
6   x4   T1   tr  0.457186  0.567753  0.095170
7   x4   T2   tr  0.553769  0.768538  0.401176
8   x5   T1  cnt  0.787308  0.036411  0.179075
9   x5   T2  cnt  0.002033  0.745652  0.638177
10  x6   T1   tr  0.954682  0.163233  0.074820
11  x6   T2   tr  0.044682  0.875726  0.538481
```